# Software Updater - Problem after Calibre upgrade

Tags: package-management, update-manager, calibre

I'm new around here so first of all sorry if this is not the right place to post.

I am using Calibre under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Recently I decided to upgrade from the version distributed through the offi*emphasized text*cial Ubuntu repositories (2.85.1) to the latest available one (3.12.0). To do so I followed the method described in https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux ("Binary install").

Calibre itself appears to have been upgraded alright, but I since I did this I keep receiving an error message when running Ubuntu Software Updater. This lists a package named "E-book converter and library management", which is obviously related to Calibre.

Under the tab "Technical Description" / "Changes" for this package I can read the following:

> "Changes for calibre-bin versions:
>   Installed version: 2.55.0+dfsg-1
>   Available version: 2.85.1-1~getdeb1 This update does not come from a
>   source that supports changelogs."

If I try to install the package, I end up in the Ubuntu error message

> "Requires installation of untrusted packages - This requires
>   installing packages from unauthenticated sources".

Can any one figure out what I should do to complete the installation of this package (or to avoid the error message each time I update Ubuntu)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because a repository with no signing key installed on your system is added to your `apt` repository list. I think this repo was added during up-gradation of that package you mentioned. To stop receiving this error all you have to do is comment out or remove that repo from `apt` repo list. To do so, run `sudo apt-get update` on terminal and look which repo is flagged as unauthenticated in the error output. This repo can be found in one of two places, in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file or in files found in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. All you have to do is comment out that repo adding `#` beginning of the line and next time you run `sudo apt-get update`, most likely you wont receive this error.